# HTML: container-fluid columns not aligned as expected

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

In my code below, I have used Bootstrap's `container-fluid` class, for a full width container. But the two columns I added are not aligned as I want to...

What I wanted is one column at the right side and the other at the very left, but it's not showing like that... Any help?

```css
.test-shine {
   
   
   background: url('https://i.pinimg.com/474x/01/88/dc/0188dc41881e0e410b5375cdead5f49a.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    height: 500px;

    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<!--<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>-->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./assets/images/letket-creative-logo.png" />
    <title>Digital Group</title>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="./assets/images/footerlogo.png">
    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http://www.google.com">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</section>
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class=" firstSection">
            <div class="row mt-5" >

        
                <div class="col firstBlockText">
                    <h4> Welcom To DigitalGroup</h4>

                    <h1>About Digital Group </h1>

                    <div class="row-hr">

                        <hr class="dot-hr">
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                    <p> <b> </b>offering digital and technology
                        investments that deliver sustainable growth yet place equal value on small and large
                        enterprises.
                        <br><br><br>

                        <b>Since 2012,</b> we’re the creator company that produce digital segments. Our success has
                        brought
                        all the digital aspects into one template of DIGITAL GROUP, relying on a team of intelligent,
                        experienced, and specialists in Digital Architecture, Digital Marketing, and Digital e-commerce.
                    </p>

                    <a class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="900" href="about.html">
                        Read more >>


                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="col test-shine">

       </div>
    </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
</section>
  <div class="container-fluid">

  <style>
 .test-shine {
   
   

    height: 500px;

    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
  


  }
  img{
    float: right;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
</section>
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class=" firstSection">
        <div class="row mt-5" >

    
            <div class="col firstBlockText">
                <h4> Welcom To DigitalGroup</h4>

                <h1>About Digital Group </h1>

                <div class="row-hr">

                    <hr class="dot-hr">
                    <hr>
                </div>
                <p> <b> </b>offering digital and technology
                    investments that deliver sustainable growth yet place equal value on small and large
                    enterprises.
                    <br><br><br>

                    <b>Since 2012,</b> we’re the creator company that produce digital segments. Our success has
                    brought
                    all the digital aspects into one template of DIGITAL GROUP, relying on a team of intelligent,
                    experienced, and specialists in Digital Architecture, Digital Marketing, and Digital e-commerce.
                </p>

                <a class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="900" href="about.html">
                    Read more >>


                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col test-shine" >
              <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/474x/01/88/dc/0188dc41881e0e410b5375cdead5f49a.jpg" alt="">
   </div>
</div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: not working still same

Comment: please check the above code which i posted.. it's working fine !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use position for align the image in your secound right container. Add only `background-position: right;` to your .test-shine class.

```css
.test-shine {


  background: url('https://i.pinimg.com/474x/01/88/dc/0188dc41881e0e410b5375cdead5f49a.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-position: right; /* this line is new */
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  
}
```

```html
<!--<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>-->
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./assets/images/letket-creative-logo.png" />
<title>Digital Group</title>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="./assets/images/footerlogo.png">
<link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http://www.google.com">-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</section>
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class=" firstSection">
    <div class="row mt-5" >


      <div class="col firstBlockText">
        <h4> Welcom To DigitalGroup</h4>

        <h1>About Digital Group </h1>

        <div class="row-hr">

          <hr class="dot-hr">
          <hr>
        </div>
        <p> <b> </b>offering digital and technology
          investments that deliver sustainable growth yet place equal value on small and large
          enterprises.
          <br><br><br>

          <b>Since 2012,</b> we’re the creator company that produce digital segments. Our success has
          brought
          all the digital aspects into one template of DIGITAL GROUP, relying on a team of intelligent,
          experienced, and specialists in Digital Architecture, Digital Marketing, and Digital e-commerce.
        </p>

        <a class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="900" href="about.html">
          Read more >>


        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="col test-shine">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i can see it working here in snippet but not in my code :\ .. also it's huge problem in my website cuz i'm using same alignment in all blocks and all of them are showing the same way ..

Comment: i'm concerning about the spaces it should be same from left and right and this is bootstrap 5 idk why it's showing that way

Comment: @darya If that not working in your code it means that something in your code make problems with this solution. Other styles overwrite some rules. If it possible you can share the css in your question.

Comment: @darya Im sorry i dont understand your comment: `im concerning about the spaces it should be same from left and right and this is bootstrap 5 idk why it's showing that way`